# How to delete folder from drawable folder of resource?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I created by mistake a folder inside `/app/src/main/res/drawable-v21/`

Now it's giving me this error
**Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png**
, but I'm not seeing that folder inside the directory.

How can i delete that folder?

Comment: Found solution--Right Click and click show in file manager,from there we can delete it.

Comment: Are you on Linux? Did you try it outside of Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

First try to undo your change by pressing ctrl+z or ctrl+alt+z

or
Open Local History view by Right click on directory and select Local History.
Revert your change to some time back.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Android Studio`, Sometimes we can't see some files or folders like your problem.

So, you could go to your `app/src/main/res` from where your project currently saved and then you could delete it.

Or, with your solution, clicking on `Show in explorer` or even when you are using `Android Studio` with collapsed project like below image:

[image]

You should be able to see all the project with any files or project with that `Project` and not `Android`.
 As you can see, i have values-v21 but i can't see that in my `Android` collapsed option.

That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

[Right click on the drawable folder and [select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4usFp.png) **Show in Explorer**]

[Here you can delete the error causing folders[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03nNu.png)